# How to remove the tick in a custom checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How can I remove the tick in the checkbox and replace it to a letter?

```
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox)
or
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wj3dm0Lt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current code, this creates the check mark:

```
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Notice that it's creating it by using the border of a rotated square (so the mark is actually the corner of a square). You can make it anything you want by removing the border properties and adding a `content: "Y"` for instance (for a Y instead of a check mark). But you'll also have to then play around with the rest of the styling on that to make it look good.

Answer (score 0):

The method I've used is to have a `<span>` element that holds the checkmark next to the `<input>` and then use CSS to hide the default style and instead position the checkmark inside. Now I was trying to replace the default one with a nice looking checkmark, you're trying to replace it with a letter.

The trickery is that I'm really using a rectangle and change the borders to turn it into a checkmark. I guess you could also just use a checkmark symbol within the span so in your situation, if you want to have a box with "A" inside when selected. Change my ::after code (get rid of the border) and put `content:"A"` instead and then just change positioning slightly.

**HTML**

```
<label class="checkbox__container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="person__checkbox" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.checkbox__container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    height: 25px;
  }

  /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
  .checkbox__container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  /* Create a custom checkbox */
  .checkbox__container .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
  .checkbox__container:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }

  /* Show the checkmark when checked */
  .checkbox__container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
  .checkbox__container .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 4px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to remove the checkmark programmatically after it has been clicked, then you can simply get the target the element using you jquery/javascript and then apply click event.

```
$('#check_box input:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).click();
});

or 

let element = document.getElementById("checkboxElement");
    element.click();
```